# Get the access token

Tags: angular, auth0

I need to get the token and it returns a lot of information

```
getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
        return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
          concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options)))
        );
      }


    const token =  auth.getTokenSilently$()
```

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-calling-an-api

[image]

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @AndrWeisR I need to get the token, but with that, I don't exactly get the token back, but a lot of information and I can't see the token

Comment: Can you post what you do get back?

Comment: The function I'm using is here. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-calling-an-api

Comment: @AndrWeisR add an image to the question

Comment: You're printing out the Observable that's returned. You need to subscribe to the Observable to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the observable in order to get the token because getTokenSilenty$ method is an observable.

Use

AuthService.ts

```js
    getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
        return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
          concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options)))
      );
    }
```

RoleGuardService.ts

```js
    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.auth.getTokenSilently$().pipe(
        first(),
        map((token) => {
          console.info(token);
          // apply here your code to get the permission
          return true;
         })
       )
     }
```

Comment: how can I store it in a variable and use that value, outside of the observable

Comment: that way, it doesn't show me anything on the console

Comment: Can you publish your code on stackblitz? That way I can help you more effectively

Comment: I don't know how to add it where you told me, serves here on github?
https://github.com/jorgnv/auth0

Comment: in auth/role.guard.service.ts I need to get the token in a variable and then use it inside CanActivate, I need to decode it to get the permissions

Comment: Try it again, Possibly you should read about Observables and Rxjs in order to understand more how Angular and Rxjs work together.

Comment: It does not mark errors, but it does not show the console token either